# Relation between controllers and compensators?

Tags: control, control-system, terminology

https://www.control.utoronto.ca/people/profs/kwong/ece311/2018/lecture_notes/lead_or_lag.pdf

Please check the above link especially the lines shown highlighted in attached snapshot.

So can we say that although PI controller and lag compensator are not exactly same but they are approximately same?

Similarly can we say that although PD controller and lead compensator are not exactly same but they are approximately same?

Is it okay to say:
**The difference between them is as follows: the compensator change the behavior of the open loop system while controller change the behavior of the close loop system.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think , some examples can clarify the situation:

**Two examples:**

**(1)** LEAD compensator: **H(s)=K(1+sTD)/(1+sT1)** with **TD>T1**

For **TD>>T1** this PD-T1 compensator approaches the **PD-controller K(1+sTD)**

**(2)** LAG compensator:  **H(s)=K(1+sT2)/(1+sT1)** with **T1>T2**

- For **T1>>T2**  this compensator approaches the **P-T1 controller K/(1+sT1)**.
- For **sT1>>1** this compensator approaches the **PI controller K(1+sT2)/sT1**.